# Upload File normally works but drag and drop doesn't

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring

If I upload the file using the normal way it works but on drag and drop i can't pass the file to the backend.

The `console.log(file);` shows the file correctly on the console.

Front end:

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#btnSubmit').html("<span class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></span> Creating");
    $('#btnSubmit').attr('disabled',true);
    var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('creationForm'));
    console.log(file);
    formData.append("fileUpload", file);

 $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/upload/testCase',
        data: formData,
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false
 // success and error
 }
```

Front End

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload/testCase" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String uploadTestCase(@RequestParam("fileUpload") MultipartFile file, ...//more stuff

The file has size 0.
```

Comment: did you look in network tools in chrome ?

Comment: The request sends it

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileUpload"; filename="teller (2).txt"
Content-Type: text/plain